# Recommended method/authentication engine to secure an API

Tags: api, oauth, openid, dotnetopenauth

Hello and thanks for looking.

## Background

I am designing an application that will host certain pieces of information/data for third-party websites via an API and must be accessed via authenticated requests.

Is OAuth the way to go about this or is there something better out there?  I will not know the domains of the third-party sites up front so I can not rely on host-headers (which can be spoofed anyway).

Requests to the API will most likely originate in jQuery or regular JavaScript on the client side.

## Question

What is the best way to ensure that third-party websites requesting data from my API are who they say they are, and are allowed to access the information they are requesting?

Many thanks!

Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OAuth, particularly OAuth 2 (which isn't yet finalized), will likely work well for you.  But since the web requests are coming from the *browser* rather than the web server hosting these web sites, each individual browser will have to be authorized rather than each domain.

So let's step back and ask this question:

> Is the data your API will be exposing unique per individual user or unique per web site domain?  Or in other words, are you as the API owner going to contractually authorize *domains* to access your data, or will individual users have data accessible via your API, and those users need to authorize these other domains to access to their own data on your service?

If you're authorizing domains (and not users) then the browser simply cannot be the initiator of these authorized requests to your API.  This is because the web server on those domains would have to issue their secret key to the client, at which point they've lost control of it and anyone can make these authorized calls -- not just the domains you've intended to authorize.  This is the "you can't trust the client" principle in security.

If you're authorizing users, then each user who visits one of these 3rd party sites will have to go through a one-time setup where the web site redirects their browser to your service to log in and say "yes, [3rd party site] can access my data", after which they're redirected back to that site.  After that, any time they visit that site, the site can download a secret key that's unique to that user and can be used from javascript on the client to make these authorized API calls.

Comment: Thanks for this great input Andrew!  The data need not necessarily user-centric at first, but ideally, the API would be flexible enough for that in the future.  Ultimately, I would like to offer certain data streams to other websites (customers) and NOT require any special middle-tier code on their part.  This is accomplished by their incorporating a jQuery plug-in I am developing and then adding certain attributes to their HTML tags that, when parsed after the DOM loads, will trigger an ajax call for the data and then the returned data is injected into the HTML tag.

Comment: All that being said, the data stream may be specific to one particular site, so I don't want other website owners to use a special HTML attribute to call data that they do not own.  Hope that makes sense.  Thanks again!